# How do I encode a normal PHP array to a JSON array keeping the indexes

Tags: php, arrays, json

Consider one simple array.

```
<?php
$a = array('a','b','c');
?>
```

how can i generate a json array as given below.

```
{
'0':'a',
'1':'b',
'2':'c'
}
```

Normal json_encode function returns ['a','b','c']

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass JSON_FORCE_OBJECT as second argument to the json_encode function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
json_encode($a, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Working perfectly. I tried

```
<?php
        $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

        $new_arr = json_encode($arr);

        print_r($new_arr);
        ?>
```

Output

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

-

Thanks

Comment: Its not what the OP wants.He had already specified the sample output.